# How to autorefresh Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/app.module.ts

When I go to "concursos/buscar": https://angular-ivy-byvfjy.stackblitz.io/concursos/buscar

I see 5 records that have the field Estudiar=null

[image: by default]

Now each time you click in one row its color changes and when the color is green that means Estudiar="SI" and when the colour is red Estudiar="NO"

After select, your desires click on Guardar button and Updates are carried out in the database via a web API call and when these updates have been made I want to reload this component so that the records with the Estudiar = null field have disappeared but

```
this.router.navigate(['concursos/buscar'])
```

don't redirect me back to the component

```
this.dataService.updateConcursosAEstudiar(concursos)
  .subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('concursos actualizados correctamente')
      this.router.navigate(['concursos/buscar'])
    }),
    err=>console.log(err)
```

if I refresh the page by hand if I see that the greens have disappeared

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: instead of refreshing the page why dont u just call the API and refresh the retrieved data ? Also, have u tried this.router.navigate([...], { relativeTo: this.parent } ) ? parent is : private parent: ActivatedRoute;

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
location.reload();
```

for reloading your current page.
it will reaload `ngOnInit` witch I assume is what you are trying to achieve but keep in mind it will display an animation of the browser refreshing.

Comment: thanks @ilay Tertman this works fine but as you say there is a refreshment that I would like to avoid.